# Panic while trying to avoid goroutine leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks, goroutine

I'm spawning some goroutines and want to hand them a channel to send back errors. In the parent goroutine, I `select` the first error and return that, or the `wg.Done()` condition, which is synchronized with closing a `done` channel.

The closing of `errc` is deferred to avoid a goroutine leak; but it causes a race condition.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func f(ch chan<- bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    log.Println("f sending a value")
    ch <- true
    log.Println("f sent a value")
}

func g(ch chan<- bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    log.Println("g sending a value")
    ch <- true
    log.Println("g sent a value")
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan bool)
    bufc := make(chan bool, 2)

    defer func() {
        log.Println("Closing bufc")
        close(bufc)
        log.Println("Closed bufc")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }()

    wg.Add(2)
    go f(bufc, &wg)
    go g(bufc, &wg)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    select {
    case done, ok := <-bufc:
        log.Printf("bufc closed: %v %v", done, ok)
    case <-ch:
        log.Println("ch was closed")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
❗ ~/c/scrap
(i) go run test.go
2018/05/01 20:28:03 f sending a value
2018/05/01 20:28:03 f sent a value
2018/05/01 20:28:03 bufc closed: true true
2018/05/01 20:28:03 Closing bufc
2018/05/01 20:28:03 Closed bufc
2018/05/01 20:28:04 g sending a value
panic: send on closed channel

goroutine 19 [running]:
main.g(0xc42009c000, 0xc42008a010)
        /Users/yangmillstheory/code/scrap/test.go:23 +0xb2
created by main.main
        /Users/yangmillstheory/code/scrap/test.go:42 +0x11e
exit status 2
```

Is there any way to do proper cleanup of the `errc` channel without causing a panic? Do I even need to close `errc`? Given that it's buffered, senders on that channel wouldn't block, so I would guess the answer is no?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is clear enough--the channel `bufc` (which I assume you refer to as `errc`) is closed before `g` can send the value to it because the `select` statement receives only once from `bufc` and it's closed by defer.  Instead of deferring the closing of `bufc` you'd have to make some synchronization, possibly using a `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure all the values are sent before closing it, for example by just moving `close(bufc)` to after `wg.Wait()`:

```
go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
        close(bufc)
}()
```

In your case since `bufc` is buffered you don't have to close it because it's not blocking on the receiving end, but once you have more than two goroutines sending you'll still need to close it to signal properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following implementation, which drains the buffered channel `bufc` and works correctly in all cases.

```
var (
    err error
    wg  sync.WaitGroup
)

ch := make(chan bool)
bufc := make(chan error, 2)

wg.Add(2)
go f(bufc, &wg)
go g(bufc, &wg)
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
    close(bufc)
}()

<-ch
log.Println("Goroutines are done")
for err = range bufc {
    log.Printf("Got an error: %v", err)
}
log.Println("Returning.")
return err
```

Comment: You should mark either answer as correct for the sake of others.

Comment: I can't do so until 6 hours from now.